# Call stored procedure in loop in wcf

Tags: c#, ajax, wcf, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have a problem with calling WCF service from ajax.

I pass to WCF an array of objects, and for every object, I need a stored procedure to be called via ADO.NET.

The problem is when I call this procedure in the loop, the application starts to lag.

Can you tell me, how is possible to fix it ?

Comment: You should post your code, including the code that calls the stored procedure.

Comment: I guess it will not be helpful, because we used own library for DB which is based on ado.net and wcf has classical implementation with operation contract.

Comment: How many items are in the list you are passing? Does the order that you process them matter?

Comment: it will be less than 10 objects and doesn't matter

Comment: Describe *starts to lag* please.

Comment: 1 loop is executed and next it freeezed, application on client side not works too.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a stored procedure you can modify? You might get significant performance benefits by modifying the stored procedure to use [table-valued parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.110).aspx). That way instead of calling the stored procedure once for every object, you're calling the stored procedure once and passing all of the objects.

The linked documentation is thorough, although you might want to google for other examples. The first time through using them you have to learn some new steps, but once you get through that it's a powerful tool for scenarios like this.

On the SQL server you create a new table-valued type. The syntax is very similar to defining a table. Then you modify your stored procedure to receive that parameter. Within the procedure you select from the parameter just like you do from a table.

In your application you create a `DataTable` which corresponds to the table you've defined and then populate it with the rows of data you want to send.

If you've ever seen anyone doing weird stuff to pass multiple values to a stored procedure (like using comma-delimited strings) this is the antidote.

Comment: @DenisStephanov this solution moves the loop into the store procedure. The loop is still going to be single threaded, so if the procedure is doing some long running process to each item you are still going to get the lag.